# How get x and y position of ScrollView in NGUI

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview, ngui

I am try to access most left and upper x and y position of ScrollView in NGUI but unable to access. i tried to access with `tranform.LocalPosition.x` but what ever value its give it is middle anchor value. I want want most left and upper position of ScrollView in NGUI.

[image]

Thanks You 
Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to look at the [UIRect](http://tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_rect.html) component of the panel. From that you can get just about any information you would want about your NGUI element.